# Multinomial Logistic Regression in R vs SPSS

Tags: r, spss, multinomial-distribution

Apologies for re-asking a closed question [previously closed since it appeared that the R and SPSS datasets were off by one value], but now that I've had the time I have a concrete example where R and SPSS give different results for the same dataset using multinom() in the nnet package in R and the NOMREG procedure in SPSS. (The default settings are being used in both cases.)

Is there a statistical reason for why this would happen? For instance, are there two different algorithms working in the back end? MLE vs. Exact Methods, or something else?

Here is some data (called dd_small below):

```
ID Group      X1     X2     X3  
1      A 111.517 -0.046 -2.908  
2      B 110.517 -0.007 -2.288  
3      A 109.517 -0.014 22.012  
4      C 110.517  0.071  2.642  
5      B 112.517 -0.024  1.352  
6      A 107.517 -0.011 -1.508  
7      A 111.517 -0.021  3.202
8      C 111.517  0.014 -3.998
9      A 108.517  0.053 -2.368
10     C 112.517  0.006  2.122
11     C 108.517  0.013 -3.998
12     C 112.517  0.066 -0.008
13     A 109.517  0.003  0.872
14     A 111.517  0.029 -3.998
15     A 110.517 -0.006  1.072
16     A 110.517  0.027  0.792
17     C 111.517 -0.021 -3.998
18     A 112.517 -0.029 -2.828
19     A 110.517 -0.047 -2.258
20     C 112.517 -0.001  3.522
21     B 111.517  0.009  1.922
22     B 108.517 -0.004  1.762
23     C 112.517  0.013  4.002
24     A 108.517 -0.047  2.082
25     A 108.517 -0.126 -0.678
26     B 107.517 -0.001  1.032
27     B 107.517 -0.002  2.682
28     A 110.517 -0.037 11.672
29     C 110.517 -0.002 14.592
30     C 106.517 -0.001 -2.218
31     C 108.517  0.026  0.712
32     A 112.517 -0.007 -0.858
33     C 107.517  0.013 -2.488
34     B 112.517 -0.019 -2.448
35     C 107.517  0.068  0.792
36     C 111.517 -0.022 -2.288
37     C 110.517 -0.036 -3.998
38     A 110.517  0.086  0.152
39     A 110.517  0.024 -2.288
40     C 109.517  0.049  6.682
41     A 109.517  0.079  1.682
42     B 108.517 -0.036 -3.998
43     A 111.517  0.071  2.722
44     B 111.517  0.023 -1.478
45     A 110.517  0.019 37.322
46     A 111.517 -0.056  0.632
47     A 109.517 -0.006 -0.488
48     A 108.517 -0.064  3.122
49     C 106.517 -0.036 -0.488
50     B 109.517 -0.029 -2.328
51     A 107.517 -0.041 26.032
52     C 109.517 -0.022  0.552
53     A 112.517  0.059  0.632
54     C 109.517 -0.026 -3.998
```

R Code:

```
library(nnet)
dd_small$Group <- relevel(dd_small$Group, ref = 'C')
test1 <- multinom(Group ~ X1  + X2*X3, data = dd_small)
summary(test1)
```

and the SPSS syntax:

```
NOMREG Group (BASE=LAST ORDER=ASCENDING) WITH X1 X2 X3

  /CRITERIA CIN(95) DELTA(0) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(5) CHKSEP(20) LCONVERGE(0) PCONVERGE(0.000001) SINGULAR(0.00000001)

  /MODEL=X1 X2 X3 X2*X3

  /INTERCEPT=INCLUDE

  /PRINT=PARAMETER SUMMARY LRT CPS STEP MFI.
```

The results are different (both parameter estimates and std. errors).

R summary Output:

```
Call:
multinom(formula = Group ~ X1 + X2 * X3, data = dd_small)


Coefficients:    
  (Intercept)          X1         X2          X3     X2:X3    
A   -6.600256  0.06216185  -7.718008  0.08511910 -3.248136    
B    1.283942 -0.01707988 -11.397056 -0.01423585 -1.524571


Std. Errors:    
  (Intercept)         X1       X2         X3    X2:X3   
A   13.890035 0.12603678  8.17223 0.06153717 2.835216    
B    8.839701 0.08045989 10.10885 0.10309833 3.927180

Residual Deviance: 104.4843     
AIC: 124.4843
```

(trimmed) SPSS Parameter Output:

```
Parameter Estimates     

Group       B   Std. Error  
A   
Intercept   -16.480 20.494              
       X1      .152   .186  
       X2    -7.331  8.157  
       X3      .085   .061  
  X2 * X3    -3.339  2.829  


B   
Intercept    -5.338 24.848              
       X1      .043   .226  
       X2   -10.315 10.031  
       X3     -.015   .103  
  X2 * X3    -1.621  3.923
```

Comment: Please print the ouptut from SPSS as well as the results from `summary` in R.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the base level rather than last? Not sure if SPSS chooses default levels based on orders in the data, (so it doesn't know A>  B> C).

Comment: Yes, base level is C in both cases (the 'relevel' in R is there to make them match). Will add the output shortly.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible for the R part, because of a typo: `dd_small <- relevel(dd_small$Group, ref = 'C')` is overwritting the `dd_small` data.frame.

Comment: Are you sure that the deviance converged? In multinom, set maxit=1000.

Comment: @williamchiu  If you run the code, it converges after 25 iterations.

Comment: Yes, there's a typo - just quickly wrote that up - it's now fixed. And yes it converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no statistical reason that the coefficients are different. You need to change the `reltol` argument to force the optimizer to keep searching for a better solution.

```r
## data

dd_small <- read.table("C:\\Users\\wchiu\\Downloads\\ddsmall.txt", header=TRUE)

head(dd_small)

dd_small$Group <- relevel(dd_small$Group, ref = 'C')

head(dd_small)


## modeling

library(nnet)

test1 <- multinom(Group ~ X1  + X2*X3, data = dd_small, maxit=1000, reltol = 1.0e-8)
summary(test1)
```

> ```
> Call:
> multinom(formula = Group ~ X1 + X2 * X3, data = dd_small, maxit = 1000, 
>     reltol = 1e-08)
>
> Coefficients:
>   (Intercept)          X1         X2          X3     X2:X3
> A   -6.600256  0.06216185  -7.718008  0.08511910 -3.248136
> B    1.283942 -0.01707988 -11.397056 -0.01423585 -1.524571
>
> Std. Errors:
>   (Intercept)         X1       X2         X3    X2:X3
> A   13.890035 0.12603678  8.17223 0.06153717 2.835216
> B    8.839701 0.08045989 10.10885 0.10309833 3.927180
>
> Residual Deviance: 104.4843 
> AIC: 124.4843
> ```

```
test2 <- multinom(Group ~ X1  + X2*X3, data = dd_small, maxit=1000, reltol = 1.0e-9)
summary(test2)
```

> ```
> Call:
> multinom(formula = Group ~ X1 + X2 * X3, data = dd_small, maxit = 1000, 
>     reltol = 1e-09)
>
> Coefficients:
>   (Intercept)         X1         X2          X3     X2:X3
> A  -16.227624 0.14950808  -7.277607  0.08514900 -3.328173
> B   -4.949933 0.03959814 -10.226522 -0.01544532 -1.616322
>
> Std. Errors:
>   (Intercept)         X1       X2         X3    X2:X3
> A   14.019095 0.12716552 8.125944 0.06125794 2.821213
> B    9.050235 0.08229205 9.971467 0.10341467 3.910369
>
> Residual Deviance: 104.2291 
> AIC: 124.2291
> ```

Comment: That's great, thanks! I'll comment further when I have time - I think the fit statistic that R uses is AIC, while SPSS uses log-likelihood but I'll have to look more closely. But thanks for getting me to actually look at the parameters involved in a bit more detail . Also, the multinom() documentation also recommends scaling the rhs variables to lie in [0,1] which isn't done in this example...Finally, it seems that nnet uses quasi-Newton optimization (optim() in r) but I can't find what SPSS uses - this might be another reason for the discrepancy.

Comment: R does not solve for the coefficients using AIC.  AIC is calculated after the coefficients are found and the log likelihood is calculated.

Comment: @JordanCollins if you like my answer, please mark as answer

Comment: Apologies: I thought I had marked it as the answer already. I would still be interested if anyone knows the 'nuts & bolts' behind R and SPSS in this regard.